# Neo4j failed to start database in Windows 10

Tags: neo4j

The Neo4j Desktop Quickstart doesn't work. It shows "Database failed to start: DB closed with exit code 1. Check the logs" 
But where is the log?

```
C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-b8d48b42-5785-4b80-9ac3-ceee47c1d6bd\installation-3.3.0\logs
```

there is a log file under that folder, but it's empty

I am running the app in admin mode, and I have tried restarting it many times.

What did I miss?

Comment: The [file location documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/) says that log files are under `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\logs` directory.

Comment: hmm, it's actually here: %APPDATA%\Neo4j Desktop, thanks

Comment: the error is this: [2017-11-09 14:37:03:0239] [warn] Analytics failed Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain. Followed by: "[error] DB database-b8d48b42-5785-4b80-9ac3-ceee47c1d6bd closed with exit code 1" How do I fix it?

Comment: i've the same problem, no solutions till now